# searching using powershell last timestamp folder

Tags: windows, powershell

i am using following powershell script for getting folder with latest time stamp

```
    $drive = get-psdrive |select root |Select-String -InputObject {$_.Root} -Pattern ':'
 Write-Host $drive

   foreach ($a in $drive)
    {            
Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Filter "*sysout" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|select -last 1       
    }

}
```

it gives following output

```
    A:\ C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\ G:\ H:\ I:\ J:\ K:\ Z:\


    Directory: E:\utility


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         2/21/2018   2:06 AM            sysout


    Directory: F:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         2/21/2018   3:15 AM            sysout
```

i need latest timestamp folder but using -last 1 doesnt give desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Last` doesn't really have any meaning without order.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $a -Filter "*sysout" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: it still pretty much giving me same result :(

Comment: @deepti what result are you expecting?

Comment: i want latest folder  where timestamp is latest 2/21/2018   3:15 AM            sysout

Comment: @deepti Latest folder _per_ drive, or latest folder across _all_ drives? What is "sysout" in this scneario?

Comment: sysout folder ALL DRIVES it checking in all drives and then give latest one

Comment: Swap `$a` with `$drive` in your code. You don't need the loop.

Comment: so this is something i tried   $drive = get-psdrive |select root |Select-String -InputObject {$_.Root} -Pattern ':'
   Write-Host $drive
 
   
Get-ChildItem -Path $drive -Filter "*sysout" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1    but iam getting one result  with timestamp 2/21/2018   2:06 AM            sysout